# Command like `column -t` but encoding-type agnostic?

Tags: unicode, csv, text, file-format

Essentially, I am looking for an encoding-type agnostic version of the `column -t` command in linux.

I need to convert delimited files to flat and then write to an outfile. The specific delimiter varies (, | \t).

Sometimes, but not always, the fields contain text characters with diacriticals.
Since `column -t` is only compatible with UTF-8 encoding type, it chokes on these "funny" characters:

I tried using commands like `file -bi` to determine encoding type so I could recode to UTF-8, but they only provide a "best guess" (which fails when the diacriticals start at row 100,000.)

So far I have come across the following:

This script in `awk` converts delimited to fixed length columns, but I need variable column widths:

```
$ awk -F@ '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){printf "%-20s", $i};printf "\n"}' input.csv
```

This script in `perl` finds max length for each column and sets each column to max length, but I also need the number of columns to be variable:

```
perl -F'\t' -lane '
BEGIN {
    open I, "< inputfile";
    for (<I>) {
        chomp;
        @x = split /\t/;
        (length ($x[0]) > $f0) && ($f0 = length ($x[0]) + 1);
        (length ($x[1]) > $f1) && ($f1 = length ($x[1]) + 1);
        (length ($x[2]) > $f2) && ($f2 = length ($x[2]) + 1);
    }
    close I;
}
print "$F[0]" . " " x ($f0 - length ($F[0])), "$F[1]" . " " x ($f1 - length     ($F[1])), "$F[2]" . " " x ($f2 - length ($F[2]));
' inputfile
```

**Does anyone have a script that:**

- Is executable in the shell
- Does what `column -t` does (deals with varying column widths, deals with varying numbers of columns, allows you to specify your delimiter)
- AND is encoding-type agnostic?

Comment: Can you provide some example of input that does not work for you? `column` should honour current locale (`LC_ALL`), but I didn't try it yet.

Comment: What do you mean by “encoding-type agnostic”? Since the task requires treating the input as a stream of characters, not a stream of bytes, it matters what the encoding of the input is. In what way is `column` not suitable? What makes you (incorrectly) believe that “column -t is only compatible with UTF-8 encoding”?